# find_or_create_by fails when used with custom ActiveModel::Validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models named Drug and Frequency.

```
#app/models/frequency.rb
class Frequency
  validates :code, presence: true
end

#app/models/drug.rb
class DrugValidator < ActiveModel::Validator                                                                                                       
  def validate(record)
    drug_attributes = {name: record.name}
    if Drug.where(name: record.name).any?
      record.errors[:base] <<  "The drug #{record.name} already exists in system."
    end
  end
end

class Drug
  validates_with DrugValidator, if: (lambda {|drug| drug.name.present?})     
end


> pf = Frequency.find_or_create_by(code: 'Q24')
Frequency Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "frequencies".* FROM "frequencies" WHERE "frequencies"."code" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["code", "Q24"]]
=> #<Frequency id: 7, code: "Q24", created_at: "2015-11-02 03:41:34", updated_at: "2015-11-02 03:41:34"> 
> pf.persisted?
=> true 
> pf.valid?
=> true 
> pf.new_record?
=> false 

> pd = Drug.find_or_create_by(name: 'SomeDrug', unit: 'tablet')
=> #<Drug id: 10, name: "SomeDrug", created_at: "2015-11-05 07:42:46", updated_at: "2015-11-05 07:42:46", unit: "tablet">
> pd.persisted?
=> true 
> pd.new_record?
=> false 
> pd.valid?
=> false
> pd.errors.messages
=> {:base=>["The drug SomeDrug already exists in system."]}
```

the custom DrugValidator is executed even when fetching the record from the system. How do i avoid this for find_or_create_by?

Answer (score 0):

Specify when this validation is active.

class Drug
  validates_with DrugValidator, if: (lambda {|drug| drug.name.present?}), on: :create
end